# C# TCP Server to Multi Clients (Unknown number of clients listening)

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, client, server

I'm trying to write a small program that is built from a Server and some Clients.
the Server will transfer / push a Text Message to the clients (the client not allowed to send back to the server, all of the clients should get the same Text Message from the server)
I've seen some question about this subject around here and over the net but did not get the exact solution I'm looking for.
most of the solutions were to create a thread for each client. but lets assume that I don't always know how many clients will  be listening on a certain time. could be 2 and could be 30.
I know there's a way of making a Thread pool and let .NET deal with assigning the threads but never had a good practice with that nor my knowledge with Threading is any good.
for now I have a simple Sever to Client program that works as expected but again, only with one client.
so here is my code:

Server:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;

namespace NetMessageServerWpf
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        TcpClient client;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
            this.listenThread.Start();
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(client == null || !client.Connected)
                client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            msg = txtMessage.Text;
            SendTCP(client);
        }

        public TcpListener tcpListener;
        public Thread listenThread;

        private string msg;

        private void ListenForClients()
        {
            this.tcpListener.Start();
        }

        public void SendTCP(TcpClient tcpClient)
        {
            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(this.msg);
            clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace NetClientSideWpf
{
    class Client : Base
    {

        private string messageString;
        public string MessageString
        {
            get { return messageString; }
            set
            {
                messageString = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MessageString");
            }
        }


        public Client()
        {
            ConnectToServer();
        }

        public void ConnectToServer()
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

            IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3000);

            client.Connect(serverEndPoint);


            NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();

            Thread ServerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            ServerThread.Start(client);


        }

        private void HandleClientComm(object client)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            byte[] message = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;

            while (true)
            {
                bytesRead = 0;

                try
                {
                    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
                }
                catch
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                MessageString = encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

any help will do! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first you should start your Listener at the start of your Application.
Then look in intervals (Timer) for ingoing connections (TCPListener.Pending http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.pending(v=vs.110).aspx)
If you get a Connection you should save the TCPClient in a List.
On Button Click send the Messages to your Clients.

I think it is not the best solution but it is one without Multiple Threads ;-)

I wrote some sample code, hope this help you (not tested):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private TcpListener _server;
    private List<TcpClient> _connectedClients;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
        _connectedClients = new List<TcpClient>();
        _server.Start();

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); //every 1 sec!
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] buffer = encoder.GetBytes(message);
        foreach (var client in _connectedClients)
        {
            NetworkStream clientStream = client.GetStream();
            clientStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            clientStream.Flush();
        }
    }


    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Tick");
        Title = "hello";

        if (_server.Pending())
        {
            _connectedClients.Add(_server.AcceptTcpClient());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I've edit my question, I forgot to mention that all the clients should get the same text message (so I think there's no need to "List" them). I don't mind using threads but how can I be sure I got enough of them etc..

Comment: you MUST list them.

You got a TcpClient per connected Client. So you have to remember all then in a List. I don't know a Property or Method on a TCPListener to send a Message to all Clients.

Comment: OK I'll try to write a sample!

Comment: Seems to work just fine so thank you :) one thing bothers me though... checking for connection every 1 sec, isn't that resource consuming? is that why you said you think it's not the best solution?

Comment: correct! I woul'd use a thread with a while loop and check there for incoming connections. but you have to lock your list of clients.

Comment: where would you put the while loop in order to get the same result but using less resources?

Comment: Can you show me what code or what you did in the DispatcherTimer class file, I trying to see how you configured the timer is the class file

Comment: Also, I got a problem, my server is no longer available to other clients when one of them disconnect, when I have three clients logged on chatting on multi-client server it works great but when one disconnects the other two can no longer switch packets. Can you help provide some code to keep the server connected for the other clients when one disconnects